# How to set the compression level for tarfile with XZ files?

Tags: python

In Python an xz tarfile can be created:

```
handle = tarfile.open(dest, 'w:xz')
```

However this doesn't set the compression level.

Is it possible to set the XZ compression level with tarfile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is a bit buried in the [`tarfile.open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.open) documentation, but it says:

> For modes 'w:gz', 'r:gz', 'w:bz2', 'r:bz2', 'x:gz', 'x:bz2', tarfile.open() accepts the keyword argument compresslevel (default 9) to specify the compression level of the file.

Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't mention `'w:xz'` as being supported.  Trying it out just in case, I can confirm that it does not.  This appears to be because the [`lzma`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/lzma.html) module doesn't support a compresslevel argument.  It does, however, support `preset`.  Why they choose a different name here?  Who knows. :-(  It does appear they made a different choice for the default compression level. With the others, they chose the maximum level by default. With xz, they chose for the default level of compression used by the tool (level 6).

Which means you'd do something like this:

```
handle = tarfile.open(dest, 'w:xz', preset=9)
```

Comment: Compresslevel works for `gz` but not `xz` in Python 3.7.  `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'compresslevel'`

Comment: Yep, discovered the same... why they chose to do it differently, I have no clue.  It really would have been nice if they had just kept the same.  It does appear they made a different choice for the default compression level.  With the others, they chose the maximum level by default.  With xz, they chose for the default level of compression used by the tool (level 6).